# Exclude test from pytest_generate_tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have a several test-files which are written in *pytest*:

**test_foo.py**:

```
class TestFoo:
    def test_foo_one(self, current_locale):
        # some actions with locale
        # assert

    def test_foo_two(self, current_locale):
        # some actions with locale
        # assert
```

**test_bar.py**:

```
class TestBar:
    def test_bar_one(self, current_locale):
        # some actions with locale
        # assert

    def test_bar_two(self, current_locale):
        # some actions with locale
        # assert
```

and **conftest.py**:

```
locales = ["da-DK", "de-DE", "en-GB", "en-US", "es-AR", "es-CO", "es-ES", "es-MX", "fi-FI"]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize('current_locale', locales, scope='session')
```

It allows to run the tests for each locale.

Now, I want to create a test where i don't need locales, and it must run at only once.
**test_without_locales.py**:

```
class TestNoLocales:
    def test_no_locales(self):
        # some actions with locale
        # assert
```

It raises an error: *ValueError:  uses no argument 'current_locale'*

How can I write the test without using current_locales?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You're just missing a check for the fixtures included in each test case.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

```
locales = ["da-DK", "de-DE", "en-GB", "en-US", "es-AR", "es-CO", "es-ES", "es-MX", "fi-FI"]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if 'current_locale' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('current_locale', locales, scope='session')
```

or you could make it even slicker by doing this:

```
params = {"current_locale": ["da-DK", "de-DE", "en-GB", "en-US", "es-AR", "es-CO", "es-ES", "es-MX", "fi-FI"]}
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    for k,v in params:
        if k in metafunc.fixturenames:
            metafunc.parametrize(k, v, scope='session')
```

This works because pytest loads each fixture in serial, so you can inject them one by one (if you have more than one param, that is)

As for excluding a test from being run, the @pytest.mark.skip() decorator's for you.